# Part of car animation scene is getting clipped out by something in viewport and final render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, world

[image: camera view issue]

below image shows the camera view in both solid and rendered views. In top image you can see part of a car is clipped out. i need to see the whole scene in camera view. this issue also exist in final render